# Generator not incrementing in strategy=GenerationType.TABLE in jpa

Tags: jpa

i am using a strategy=GenerationType.TABLE  on my Employee table and i defined a generator using @TableGenerator(name="Empl_Gen", table="ID_GEN",pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE") and specified the generator in @GeneratedValue(generator="Emp_Gen") using the name of the generator which is "Empl_Gen". when the application starts up , it creates a table named "ID_GEN" but the table dont contain any Generator of the name ""Empl_Gen".Infact it will create a generator "EMPLOYEE" which is same as my entity class name. Also the value of the ""GEN_VALUE" doesnt get incremented when persisting the employee entity.The ids for the employee are generated randomly too..

```
package com.test.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
public class Employee {

@TableGenerator(name="Empl_Gen", table="ID_GEN",pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE")
@Id@GeneratedValue(generator="Empl_Gen",strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

private String Name;

private String Country;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}
```

}

Comment: you mean to say in the ID_GEN table it creates a ROW with GEN_NAME="EMPLOYEE" ? yes, that's what it should do ... the generated value for the Employee's table. It will create BLOCKS of ids (why any table generator has an initialValue and an allocationSize). Post the SQL issued, and the persistence code that matches that SQL. And mention WHICH JPA IMPLEMENTATION while you're at it.

Comment: Yes sir, its creating the the row With GEN_NAME="EMPLOYEE", but as written in the book which i m currently reading(pro jpa 2 by Mike Keith & Merrick) he writes it as: "The name of the generator becomes the value stored in the pkColumnNamecolumn for that row and is used by the 
provider to look up the generator to obtain its last allocated value". And sir can you just elobrate the concept of blocks of ids.

Comment: here is my SQL issued :.....Hibernate: insert into ID_GEN(GEN_NAME, GEN_VALUE) values('Employee', ?)
Hibernate: update ID_GEN set GEN_VALUE = ? where GEN_VALUE = ? and GEN_NAME = 'Employee'
Hibernate: insert into Employee (Country, Name, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: You mean the book written by EclipseLink authors about the EclipseLink implementation (NOTHING in the JPA spec defines what should go in that table). And which implementation are you using?

Comment: sorry for last comment, i am using jpa 2.0 implementation

Comment: sir ,i got it..you,meant to say that until the allocation size wont be used up, the "GEN_VALUE" column wont increment if the allocationSize attribute , which gets a default of 50 is left from the @TableGeneration? right?

Comment: yes, the JPA implementation will allocate 50 (unless you change the default allocationSize) and reserve those internal to the JVM, and use them if any other persists come in. If no other persists come in then the next time the generator is needed it allocates the next 50 ... so you may get 1, 51, 101 etc

Comment: thanks so much sir..i appreciate this